# Removing the square root in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+3}}{4n^2+n+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know I can use the comparison test to examine this series, but say I wanted to take the limit of this series, how do I handle square root in the series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{n+3}}{4n^2+n+4}$$
For example, if there wasn't a square root I would just divide all the terms in the numerator and denominator by the highest power of $n$. But I just don't see how I do that algebraically with a square root.

Comment: Do you mean you want a closed form for the sum?  I  doubt that there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+3}}{4n^2+n+4}\le\frac{\sqrt2\sqrt n}{4n^2+n+4}\le\frac{\sqrt2}4\frac{\sqrt n}{n^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\frac1{n^{3/2}}$$

and now apply the $\;p-$ series criterion: the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

You can still divide top and bottom by $n^2$ if you want to (multiplying each term by $\frac{1/\sqrt{n^4}}{1/n^2}$.  It may not help you do anything though.